# defining dispatcher for akka actor when named with UUID

Tags: java, playframework, akka, actor, dispatcher

I have a play application built on java using Akka actor. Recently I came across performance issues with related to parallelism. I have gone through Google and found that we can assign custom/pinned dispatchers/executors to actors. At the time of actor creation, I have named the actor with actor name appended with unique ID.

Is there a way to specify my actors to use pinned dispatcher when the actor names are appended with unique ID.

I am trying to update the application.conf as below and not getting the result as expected. It is still using default dispatcher.

My actors are at akka://application/user/actor

```
akka.actor.deployment {
  "/actorName*" {
       dispatcher =  mycustom-dispatcher
  }
}
```

References I used: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.4/java/dispatchers.html#Setting_the_dispatcher_for_an_Actor

Comment: The latest config reference ( http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.17/java/dispatchers.html ) doesn't have a wildcard * in its example. have you tried without it? Are you sure there are no typos anywhere? How are you confirming it's still using the default one?

Comment: @Diego, the logs confirming that the actor using the default dispatcher.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can explicitly assign a dispatcher to your actor[s].

```
import akka.actor.Props
val myActor =
  context.actorOf(Props[MyActor].withDispatcher("my-dispatcher"), "myactor1")
```

or java variant:

```
ActorRef myActor =
  system.actorOf(Props.create(MyUntypedActor.class).withDispatcher("my-dispatcher"),
    "myactor3");
```

with configuration

```
my-dispatcher {
  executor = "thread-pool-executor"
  type = PinnedDispatcher
}
```

Check for more the [akka-docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/dispatchers.html#Setting_the_dispatcher_for_an_Actor)

Comment: I am looking for an option by not touching the actor. Is there a way to mention through configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify which dispatcher to use with your actors, usually you pass an execution context where you can specify which dispatcher to use:

```
implicit val executionContext = system.dispatchers.lookup("my-dispatcher")
```

You can also change the default dispatcher like specified here:
https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/dispatchers.html#default-dispatcher

Answer (score 0):

```
akka.actor.deployment {
  "/actorName*" {
    dispatcher =  mycustom-dispatcher
  }
}
```

The above doesn't work, because (from the [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/java/general/configuration.html#actor-deployment-configuration)):

> - wildcards **cannot** be used to partially match section, like this: `/foo*/bar`, `/f*o/bar` etc.

You can, however, use a wildcard to match all actors at a certain level in the actor hierarchy. For example, let's say that all of the actors for which you want to use the custom dispatcher live under `akka://application/user/someParent/`. You could then configure all of `someParent`'s direct children in the following way:

```
akka.actor.deployment {
  "/someParent/*" {
    dispatcher =  mycustom-dispatcher
  }
}
```

Read the linked documentation for more options.